# Why is learning slower for a sigmoid activation function in a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, sigmoid-curve

Andrew Ng in one of his deep learning course videos says that the sigmoid function acts as a slow learner in a neural network.

My intuition is that the sigmoid as an activation function contributes very less to the change in the input for the tail part (after 4 in the fig).
[image: Sigmoid]

Please help me understand the intuition of the statement in detail.

Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: Slow compared to what?

Comment: Slow compared to ReLU, I assume... for the reasons given in the question itself.

Comment: This may help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126238/what-are-the-advantages-of-relu-over-sigmoid-function-in-deep-neural-networks

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but yes, slow in comparison with other activation functions like ReLU.